# upstart jobs - privileged vs unprivileged

Tags: memory, upstart

On one of my VMs, some `upstart` jobs were failing, and when I checked 
`df`, showed that I had run out of disk-space (`Use%` was `100` on `/dev/sda1`).

What I did not get is: the jobs which were running with a `setuid` were failing, but the ones running as `root` were able to start!, 
If I removed `setuid`, even the failed ones could be started!

Answer (score 1):

I am not an upstart expert, but I think, that jobs running as `root` are using disk preserved space (5% of partition space are preserved for `root` as default).

Comment: oh! OK, wasn't aware of it